# Firestore doesn't listen for query (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to listen to document changes with the following code: (Flutter)

```
   Firestore.instance
        .collection('myCollection')
        .where("owners.${myUserID}", isEqualTo: true)
        .orderBy("lastRef", descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {
      print("listening");
      data.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
        setState(() {
          myList = data.documents;
        });
      });
    });
```

This code only works once, it adds all the right documents to the list, but when a document is updated, it doens't do anything...

I tried this code (without the where query)

```
   Firestore.instance
        .collection('myCollection')
        .orderBy("lastRef", descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {
      print("listening");
      data.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
        setState(() {
          myList = data.documents;
        });
      });
    });
```

Works perfectly, even when a document is updated

I thought I'd had to make an index, but i didn't see any message in the console. 
Tried creating one manually.

```
Indexed fields: owners (array), lastRef (descending)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update your question to show: 1) the value of `myUserID`? (for example, by printing it right before you run the query), 2) a screenshot of a document that should be returned by the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `data.documentChanges.forEach((change) {` around the `setState` call looks suspicious to me. As far as I can see you should set the documents to the state, whenever your listener gets called.

So something like:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('myCollection')
    .where("owners.${myUserID}", isEqualTo: true)
    .orderBy("lastRef", descending: true)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) {
  setState(() {
    myList = data.documents;
  });
});
```

I doubt it'll change the problem with your query, but I'd recommend changing this either way as it simplifies your listener and makes it more idiomatic.